# 'context.getTwilioClient(...).document is not a function?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm working with Twilio Functions and I'm trying to use [Sync Documents](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/sync-documents) but I keep getting this error: `context.getTwilioClient(...).document is not a function`

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  context.getTwilioClient().document('data').then(function(doc) {..});
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what Sync Documents is, but the Twilio Client doesn't have a document object or property on it

Comment: I found it here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/sync-documents

Comment: Ok. I believe that `client` you are getting is the Twilio client, not a "sync" client. See the examples here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/rest/documents
(Edited my wording)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Andy said, the client you retrieve from `context.getTwilioClient()` is a generic Twilio REST API client that can access all the resources.

To [get your document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/rest/documents) you need to traverse the objects in the client and get a handle on your [service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/rest/services). You need the Sync Service SID, ideally in your environment variables, and the code would look like this:

```
const client = context.getTwilioClient();
const service = client.sync.services(process.env.SYNC_SERVICE_SID);
service.document('data').fetch().then(function(doc) {
  // do something with the document.
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.